# Border around td on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table

When viewed on mobile, there is a border around the td `class="pos-nochange"` even though border is set to 0px. And one thing I don't understand is why do the borders get bigger or smaller (looks pretty unfixed) as a user zooms in (scales bigger) on their mobile devices?

```
<table style="font-family: Open Sans; font-size:12px; border:0px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #44445e;" colspan="5" width="300">
                <div id="mleaguetable"></div>
                <div class="live"><span style="font-size:15px">LIVE</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: #050528; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" colspan="2" height="30"><strong><span style="color: #828293;">Pos</span></strong>
            </th>
            <th style="background-color: #050528; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;" width="155"><strong><span style="color: #828293; padding: 0 0 0 5px;">Club</span></strong>
            </th>
            <th style="background-color: #050528; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="50"><strong><span style="color: #828293;">Pld</span></strong>
            </th>
            <th style="background-color: #050528; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="50"><strong><span style="color: #828293;">Pts</span></strong>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #51516d; vertical-align: middle; text-align: right;" width="30" height="30"><span style="color: #ffffff;">1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="pos-nochange" style="background-color: #51516d;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: #51516d; border-right: 1px solid #44445E;"><span style="color: #ffffff; padding: 0 0 0 5px;"><a href="/en-gb/clubs/profile.overview.html/arsenal"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Utd For Utd</span>
                </a>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: #51516d; text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #44445E;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">5</span>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: #51516d; text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ffffff;">13</span></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add `border-collapse:collapse` style-rule to your `<table>` ignore inline style, better make classes!

Comment: try using `!important`. put this code at the end of the `border:1px solid #e1e1e1 !important;`

Comment: Yeap, I'm going for classes but I'm just showing you guys so you can spot where the error was from easily. I'll try and update again.

Comment: Am I doing it wrongly? It doesn't work. Try using your mobile (table on the right sidebar). www.sefcl.sg

Answer (score 1):

Use [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) style rule:

```
table
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[**<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/j54VQ/)

Answer (score -1):

Add inline attribute `border=""` to table.

Comment: Please justify the down vote. To the person who voted only to train his finger, let me quote you something: "In HTML5, the border attribute is only used to indicate if the table is for layout purposes or not, and the only allowed attribute values are "" or "1"."

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't explain why the border only appears on the `td.pos-nochange`. Also, much better to recommend the use of CSS to achieve this, rather than recommending HTML attributes. CSS was designed to separate design from mark-up, and should be used as such.

Comment: @BenM As i can see from this mark-up, all the styles are inline. So, where is the separation in this case?

Comment: See his comment: `Yeap, I'm going for classes but I'm just showing you guys so you can spot where the error was from easily. I'll try and update again`

Comment: OK, then will `colspan="5"` go into a class? So if it wont, how one more inline attribute will be a bad practice?

Comment: You miss my point. `border` serves no other purpose than for styling. `colspan` and other attributes have semantic purpose.

Comment: `border`, as much as `colspan` are meant for table structure. I really don't see the semantic scope of the `colspan`. But anyway, i'll end this discussion, so we don't clutter the topic with unnecesary things. @D. Wong - use `border-collapse:collapse` to make cell styling to work